# ActionMailer observers not working with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, delayed-job

I have an ActionMailer observer that's working just fine during normal sends, but when I send the delivery to delayed_job, it doesn't get called at all. Is this a function of delayed_job itself, or something specific with my observer?

Controller:

```
BulkMailer.delay.blast(recipients, email, template)
```

Initializer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailObserver)
```

Observer

```
class MailObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    Rails.logger.debug 'Message: finished'
  end
end
```

Comment: did u try restarting the delayed_job after done above changed !

Comment: I've run into this as well. When switching between git branches or before testing mail-related functionality I'm sure to restart workers. From [Resque's GitHub page](https://github.com/defunkt/resque), "By default Resque won't know about your application's environment. That is, it won't be able to find and run your jobs - it needs to load your application into memory." Resque rocks, but it's a small gotcha to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself was fine, Delayed Job and ActionMailer observers are compatible. My problem was solved by restarting the workers.

Comment: Is the answer comprehensive enough now?